# Generating custom text files in java

Tags: java, csv, fileinputstream, file-writing

```
public class ScriptCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        #Choose the CSV file that I am importing the data from
        String fName = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Downloads\\CurrentApplications (1).csv";
        String thisLine;
        int count = 0;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fName);
        DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
        int i = 0;
        #Prints the List of names in the CSV file
        while((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null){
            String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");
            Printer(strar[0]);
        }

    }

    public static void Printer(String arg) throws IOException{      
        #Want to pull from the String strar[0] from above
        #Says that it cannot be resolved to a variable      
            String name = arg;
            String direc = "C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/";
            String path = "C:/Users/MyUser/Documents";
            Iterable<String> lines = Arrays.asList("LOGIN -acceptssl ServerName","N " + name + " " + direc ,"cd " + name,"import " + path  + "*.ppf" + " true","scan", "publishassessase -aseapplication " + name,"removeassess *","del " + name );
            Path file = Paths.get(name + ".txt");
            Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    }

}
```

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for any help that you may be able to give me. I am trying to create a java program that will pull names from a CSV file and take those names to generate custom outputs for text files. I am having a hard time being able to set a variable that I can use to grab the names that are being printed and using them to generate a text file by setting the name variable.
I am also going to need some help in making sure that it creates the amount of scripts for the amount of names in the CSV file. Ex. 7 names in CSV makes 7 custom .txt files, each with its appropriate name.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:   I have updated my code to match the correction that was needed to make the code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some scoping issues. Whenever you declare a variable, it only exists within the boundaries of its closest set of braces. By declaring strar in your main method, the only place you can explicitly use it is within your main method. Your Printer() method doesn't have any previous mention of strar, and the only way it can know about it is by passing it as an argument to the function.

i.e.

```
Printer(String[] args)
```

Or, better yet:

```
Printer(String arg)
```

and then call it in your while loop with

```
Printer(strar[0]);
```

Also, your Printer method begins with a "for each" loop called on strar[0], which is not a valid target for a foreach loop anyway, because if I recall correctly, String isn't an Iterable object. If you implemented the Printer function in the way I recommended, you won't need a for each loop anyway, as there will only be one name passed at a time.

Comment: You happen to be one of my favorite people right now. It worked!! I tried to up-vote but I don't have a high enough reputation for that.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help :)